# Pushing element into array where the object is specified by the user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to manually specify the object 'data1.authNames' & 'data2.authNames' from html and trying to push an object onto it. I get 'Cannot call method 'push' of undefined' where am I going wrong ?

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="setAuthName('data1.authNames')">Button1</button>
    <button ng-click="setAuthName('data2.authNames')">Button2</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 =  $scope.data2 = {};
  $scope.data1.authNames = [];
  $scope.data2.authNames = [];

  $scope.setAuthName = function(obj){
    $scope.obj.push("Hello");
  }

});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/xJ42UxQBVYYyFg8ljLDu?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$scope.setAuthName = function(obj){
    getProp($scope, obj).push("Hello");
};

function getProp(obj, prop){
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    var _ref = obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        var part = parts[i];
        if(i === parts.length - 1)
            return _ref[part];
        else
            _ref = _ref[part] || {};
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: you also have other mistakes there, take a look at this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = { authNames: [] };
  $scope.data2 = { authNames: [] };

  $scope.setAuthName = function(obj){
    var o = getProp($scope, obj);
    o.push("Hello");
    console.log(o);
  }

  function getProp(obj, prop){
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    var _ref = obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        var part = parts[i];
        if(i === parts.length - 1)
            return _ref[part];
        else
            _ref = _ref[part] || {};
    }
  }
});
```